# How to export assets using the export Usergrids export tool

Tags: apigee, usergrid

When I run the export command here below it creates a new export folder containing a set of JSON files that corresponds to the different apps and organisations I have.

```
$ java -jar usergrid-tools.jar export
```

Unluckly the Assets (files) I've stored are not exported, how do I export them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting assets is not supported at this time.  I have opened a ticket in our JIRA and you can track it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/USERGRID-997